# Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...).click is not a function on automated process

Tags: javascript, html

Expected Behaviour: I am adding the value from a select element to a 3rd party API input element using the select element's onchange event. Once the text value has been added to the input element, the search button must be clicked to fully automate the process.

[image: Select element selection]

[image: 3rd Party Api text gets added]

Returned Behaviour: Although the text value can be seen in the input, once it gets focus, it clears the text. When the text is visible and the search button is clicked, nothing happens. When I add the text value manually to the input and then click search it works fine. Not too sure what to do to make sure the text remains in the input.

Code for my select and the input as follow -

```js
function vehicle_vin() {
  var use_vehicle_vin = document.getElementById('get_vehicle_make');
  use_vehicle_vin = use_vehicle_vin.options[use_vehicle_vin.selectedIndex].value;

  var add_vehicle_vin = document.getElementById('id-vin-frame-search');
  add_vehicle_vin.value = use_vehicle_vin;
  alert(add_vehicle_vin.value);
  //This works fine, but please see my notes above, when I put focus on the input, my value dissapears...

 //I have tried, as per various search results the following QuerySelector, no luck in the search button being clicked.
 //document.querySelector('.CLOYw6ixbVCoWy9pu904a ._2DcnCzqTJKrTWusHYHyHEf').click();
 //I then changed to the svg element, the same error was returned...
 var x_vin = document.querySelector('._15YY4Hl-2b6wr1smId9ZlA').click();

 //I also tried to do a setTimeout, also did not work, then added the below, this returns nothing -.
 if (x_vin && x_vin.length) {
    alert("All true, click...");
    setTimeout(() => { x_vin[0].click(); }, 750);
    alert("clicked");
 } else {
    alert("not clicked");
 }
}
```

```html
<select id="get_vehicle_make" name="get_vehicle_make" title="Select a vehicle from your current car park. This V.I.N. will be added to the Search Input and will automatically load your search." onchange="vehicle_vin();">
  <option value="" selected >Select Saved Vehicle</option>
  <option value = "123456asdfgh09876" >Kia, Sportage, 2. CRDi</option>
 </select>
    <!--3rd party Api input and search button-->
    <input type="text" id="id-vin-frame-search" name="vin-frame-search" placeholder="VIN or FRAME" class="_2UbmnxPVuhV1aqBHdE1oDO">
    <button type="button" class="CLOYw6ixbVCoWy9pu904a _2DcnCzqTJKrTWusHYHyHEf">
 <span class="_24-MeE_aY0KDledQMmmJAn">
  <svg width="16" class="_15YY4Hl-2b6wr1smId9ZlA">
   <use xlink:href="#search"></use>
  </svg>
 </span>
    </button>
```

As above, I have tried many things with no success and will really appreciate any help available, javascript is not my strong point...

Comment: there is no click() handler, use onclick() to register your own handler behaviour ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers. Im trying to understand what you are expecting click() to actually do?

Comment: Thank you, this looks like what I have been searching for, will implement and update here.

Comment: My apologies, I thought your link will work for me, not what I am looking for unfortunately as it covers events to an element, I want to have an element clicked via Javascript. To answer your question, the search icon is clicked and the 3rd party API then does a search for that vehicle from their database as per image above.

Comment: sounds like you want to trigger a click event on your span, but this makes no sense on the span you have defined, as there is no click event handler associated with it - in what you have provided....   you can trigger events ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events - but you have to have something to handler them.  What are you expecting the click to actually do?

Comment: @developer, you are a hero, the span actually did the trick, I tried to "code click" the button and the svg to no avail. I tried the span element and it works, gets clicked automatically. I am still stuck with the first part of my problem - input text is copied over but is not "read" when clicking the search, have to manually type it into input. Any ideas here? Pse keep in mind that I have no control over the input or the span/button/svg apart from interacting with them via javascript. As per my above code, the input is a text and id is correct, see image 2 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `querySelector` returns single element, to get multiple elements use
   `querySelectorAll`

   As you are trying to access single and first element, then you can use `querySelector`.
   So the `x_vin` will contain element directly (not nodelist)
2. So you are trying to click element programmatically (From Javascript), Then you have `.click()` function

Just wrapped the `click` function in `timeout` (e.g., below)

```
setTimeout(() => {
 console.log(document.querySelector('._15YY4Hl-2b6wr1smId9ZlA'));
 document.querySelector('._15YY4Hl-2b6wr1smId9ZlA').click();
}, 1000) //1 second delay
```

**Update**

> Hey I just found that `svg` does not have `click` function (I thought
>   every element does). Solution is to click parent element
>   programmatically, In your case either click `span` or `button`

Comment: Thank you Sameer, same error is returned - ims_user_franchise_dealer.php:391 Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...).click is not a function, I also tried it again without the setTimeout, also again same error. The element is returned as a [object SVGSVGElement]

Comment: Thank you again, the problem was solved by using click on the span element as per developer above. I have also manage to solve the first part by putting focus to the input element, and then copy the value over in a setTimeout way as per your suggestion, thank you very much!